# Natural Join of two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I've been looking over this code for the better part of the last hour trying to figure out my misstep. It's probably glaringly obvious, but after so long in front of the computer, I may just need a second set of eyes to have it pop out. I have multiple tables connected to keep them 1NF and 2NF, but there are two tripping me up.

I have a main table, called my_contacts, and one holding the state/city information, called zip_code. zip_code holds the primary key row 'zip_code' with my_contacts holding its foreign key.

Problem is, when I try to join them I get nothin'. Did I screw up somewhere? Below are the SHOW CREATE TABLEs for each:

For my_contacts:

```
    CREATE TABLE `my_contacts` (
    `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `prof_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `zip_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`),
    KEY `mc_profid_fk` (`prof_id`),
    KEY `my_zip_fk` (`zip_code`),
    CONSTRAINT `mc_profid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`prof_id`) 
    REFERENCES `profession` (`prof_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `my_zip_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`zip_code`) REFERENCES `zip_code` (`zip_code`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

for zip_code:

```
    CREATE TABLE `zip_code` (
    `zip_code` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`zip_code`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the query you are using to select?  Are you sure you have data in both tables? Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I was using a pretty simple NATURAL JOIN:

    `SELECT mc.first_name, mc.last_name, zc.state`
    `FROM my_contacts mc`
    `NATURAL JOIN zip_code zc;`

Both tables have data in them. I will append the above code to include what is listed in each, if that will help.

Comment: Is zip code a real zip code? You have it as an auto increment in the `zip_code` table.

Comment: No, zip_code isn't an actual zip code, it's just what I used for the primary key for that field. Each entry is only one integer in the zip_code field. There are only four entries in each table. zip_code has 4, each with their own unique primary key, and same for my_contacts. zip_code column in my_contacts is NULL. Should that show a value? I have tried giving each its respective value (as per the contact_id in my_contacts), but the natural join still produces nothing. I get no errors, just no data.

Comment: Why would you expect a join to work if the value on one side is NULL?

Comment: Plus, if it's not actually a zip code, then why confuse the issue by naming it that.  You'd probably be better off calling the column zip_key or something similar.  Plus, in your zipcodes table, you probably would want to store the actual zip code, in order to be able to mail something.  But this seems a bit redundant.  You could just use real zip code values as @Gordon suggested.  The only drawback is if you feel you need multiple records for some zip codes, as there can be multiple city names allowed for many USPS zip codes, as well as many zip codes for a single city name.

Comment: @KMcK My suggestion would be to edit your original post with some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip_code` in the `zip_code` table is set to auto_increment.

This doesn't seem like a likely choice for this field in that table.  Where do you actually store the `zip_code`?  By the way, I would expect the actual zip code to be stored as a character string, to handle leading 0s.  A zip code may look like a number, but it really isn't one (ordering is not very well defined, and arithmetic operations make no sense).